# Call method values on page behind

Tags: asp.net

i have this method in mail.cs file which take one parameter,call store procedures and and return values from database.

```
   public void select(string type)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EmailSetup_CRUD"))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type);






        }

    }
}
```

i want to call the return values from this method on page behind and bind it with label. please advice how to do it.

on my page behind on page load i have done like this

```
    mail callmail = new mail()
```

now  i label1.text how to assign return value to label1.text.

method returns 5 column and i have 5 label on my page so each column will assign to each label.

Comment: Your code is incomplete, what kind of data you are getting from the procedure and which way you are using to fetch the records DataReader or DataAdapter please specify

Comment: its return string values , please suggest which way is better is datareader or data adapter

Comment: Are you doing anything after this "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type);" ?

Comment: no i am not doing any thing after this. i do not what to do after this to fetch the data

Comment: You should have idea about DataReader or DataAdapter or ADO.NET in general to understand how it work

Comment: can you help to complete the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174984/discussion-between-zaki-mohammed-and-user3597236).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the discussion and assumptions I made following code

mail.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace tempApp4
{
    public class mail
    {
        public DataTable select(string type)
        {            
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("EmailSetup_CRUD", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Action", "SELECT");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type);

                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

                    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

                    return dataSet.Tables[0];
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

WebForm1.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="tempApp4.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="label3" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="label4" runat="server" />
        <asp:Label ID="label5" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace tempApp4
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mail mail = new mail();

            var table = mail.select("TYPE_VALUE");

            label1.Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][0]);
            label2.Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][1]);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][2]);
            label4.Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][3]);
            label5.Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][4]);
        }
    }
}
```

SqlDataAdapter "adapter" used to fetch records from the DB and fill it in dataSet. Data set holds many table as your procedure returns single table the "select" method returns single table at the end as:

```
return dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Thus "select" method have return type as "DataTable". Then finally access returned value in code behind using mail class's object and filling the labels by accessing the column as follows:

```
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0][0]);
```

The first 0 in "table.Rows[0][0]" is for rows and second is for column. For column optionally you can specify name of the column as:

```
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows[0]["COLUMN_NAME"]);
```

Since I don't know the column names I am using indexing.

Hope it helps